# Getting an error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "VOID": invalid identifier

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Getting an error for the following code:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "VOID": invalid identifier

```
String sql = "UPDATE eidm_person_resource SET activeFlag=? WHERE employee_number = " + employee_number;
String activeFlag = "N";

public boolean updateActiveFlag() {
    String sql = "UPDATE test SET active_flag=? WHERE employee_number = " + employee_number;
    
    Connection con1 = null;
    PreparedStatement prSt1 = null;
    ResultSet checkRS = null;
    int upsertCount = 0;
    String activeFlag = "N";

    
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
      String pw = context.decrypt("*******");
      con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("**********");
      prSt1 = con1.prepareStatement(sql);

      prSt1.setString(1, activeFlag);
        System.out.println(sql);
      upsertCount = prSt1.executeUpdate();
      if (upsertCount == 1) {
        System.out.println("+++ updated record to test for " + employeeNumber);
      }
    
    prSt1.close();
    con1.close();
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: `ORA-00904-invalid identifier` errors are frequently caused by case sensitivity issues. Oracle does not support case-insensitivities double-check column names

Comment: There is nothing in your code called, "VOID".  is this a [mcve]?

Comment: String sql = "UPDATE test SET active_flag=? WHERE employee_number = " + employee_number;
This line is throwing the exception.

Comment: Also, I just changed the above line with some changes to the quotes.
String sql = "UPDATE test SET active_flag='?' WHERE employee_number = '" + employee_number + "'";

I get the error:
The application script threw an exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column.

Comment: Check this link for details on this issue: [ORA-00904](https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-00904-invalid-identifier/). Your table is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your employee_number has no valid value?

I recommend you using a parameterized query. You started your Query with

```
active_flag = ?
```

and set the value in the PreparedStament with

```
prSt1.setString(1, activeFlag);
```

Try using the same with employee_number.

```
prSt1.setLong(2, employee_number);
```